# Convert text to number values after Query Editor (stored as text)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, excel-2013, excel-2016

Consider 2 sheets, one sheet is lookup one where I am taking my data (matching them with another sheet) using this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Sheet2!A:Y;MATCH($U17;Sheet2!A:A;0);MATCH(X$14;Sheet2!2:2;0))=1;"n.k.";"");"")
```

But,there is a problem with a number values format after I upload them into PowerQuery and after they are imported as Pivot table. They have to be in TEXT format during PowerQuery but afterwards only "numerical values" is what I needed.

This picture down shows text format after Pivot (1 ´s are on left as text stored)

[image: After Pivot]

This picture shows as I need to have, numbers are moved on very right (I did it manually).

[image: Numerical Values should be on right]

Problem is when I try to "match" this table inside my formula it gives me empty space, even if it is "number" on certain places. So, cant read it somehow after Query.

I tried: `=Value` `=substitute` `A1+0`

Also, I checked with `isnumber and istext` and is TRUE for `istext` but, cant manage to combine it properly with all of these functions.

Anyone has a suggest? I cant do it manually, because of the Refresh of data that are gonna be populated, and that brings me back at the beginning.

I am using office 2016 btw.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your Power Query (M) code. Why do "They have to be in TEXT format during PowerQuery" ?

Comment: @Olly because it is csv file and I need to have it as it is in the same Workbook, but different sheet , so I can lookup data from. Previously I had to open that csv sheet, update with new data, use a function to copy it to my main workbook. This is only quicker way I guess to have all in one workbook, update on reshresh (that csv because it is generated alwys the same and cant change anything inside), and use index/match to my main table.